# Set width percentage to another width

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

Using Xcode's Interface Builder, how would I set the width of ABC view to be 30% the width of ZYZ view? In this case, XYZ view can be the super view of ABC view or it can be another view on the same view hierarchy level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the 2 views, and give them an equal width constraint. Edit this constraint to make the multiplier 0.3 (or 3.33 depending on which item is the first one in the constraint).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer rdelmar. That does it.

Comment: You can also set it use fraction such as 1:3.